# Top-aligning equations in multicols

Tags: equations, multicol, columns

Using the `multicols` environment works fine to make to columns in the middle of a document with text. But it doesn't seem to work in the same way with an `align` environment

Code snippet and example picture added below. As shown, the two columns are made as always, but the equation part is not aligned to the top of the first column. It looks shifted a bit downwards. It looks like the `align` environment wants to be lower than the other column, since its upper margin to other text has grown here.

Is there a way to control the position of the `\begin{align*}` environment in such a `\begin{multicols}` environment so that the `align` part with the math is moved further up (as the arrow indicates)?

---

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}    %Character set
\usepackage{amsmath}    %Math
\usepackage{amssymb}    %Symbols
\usepackage{graphicx}   %Figures 
\usepackage{enumitem}   %List proporties
\usepackage{multicol}           %Coloumns

\newcommand*{\Scale}[2][4]{\scalebox{#1}{\ensuremath{#2}}}%

\begin{document}

\textit{Decimal numbers} --- Every new digit represents a factor of 10.

\begin{multicols}{2}
    \begin{align*}
    \xleftarrow{\times 10\text{ bigger}}&\xrightarrow{\times 10\text{ smaller}}\\
    \Scale[3]{647}\Scale[3]{.} & \underbrace{\Scale[3]{235}}_\text{decimal places}
    \end{align*}
    \tiny
    \begin{itemize}[noitemsep]
        \item 6 hundreds
        \item 4 tens
        \item 7 ones
        \item 2 tenths
        \item 3 hundredths
        \item 5 thousandths
    \end{itemize}
    \normalsize
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Like in your other questions: A **full** example would be nice. Where is `\Scale` etc. from?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Sure thing. Full working code added.

Comment: In fact, unless more two-column stuff is needed, I would use tabular spanning the width of the text and two table columns instead. Or `paracols` package

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion you're using the wrong tools:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}    %Character set
\usepackage{amsmath}    %Math
\usepackage{amssymb}    %Symbols
\usepackage{graphicx}   %Figures
\usepackage{enumitem}   %List proporties
\usepackage{multicol}           %Coloumns

\newcommand*{\Scale}[2][4]{\scalebox{#1}{\ensuremath{#2}}}%

\begin{document}

\textit{Decimal numbers} --- Every new digit represents a factor of 10.
\[
\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}c@{}c@{}}
\scriptsize$\times 10$ bigger && \scriptsize$\times 10$ smaller \\[-1.5ex]
\leftarrowfill && \rightarrowfill \\
\Scale[3]{647}&\Scale[3]{.} & $\underbrace{\Scale[3]{235}}_\text{decimal places}$
\end{tabular}
\qquad
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\tiny
\begin{tabbing}
\textbullet\ \= \kill
\textbullet\ \> 6 hundreds \\
\textbullet\ \> 4 tens \\
\textbullet\ \> 7 ones \\
\textbullet\ \> 2 tenths \\
\textbullet\ \> 3 hundredths \\
\textbullet\ \> 5 thousandths
\end{tabbing}
\end{minipage}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]